# How to change text font size svg while drag the corror of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg

I want to change font-size while enlarging the text shown in image. I tried but size isn't changing. Can anyone help me to change font-size based on the text resize.

Kindly see my image.[image]

[image]

Comment: what is this? is it a library for resizing elements? is it in a browser?

Comment: Resizing working for me. My doubt is change font-size while enlarging the text shown in image. By default size is 24px, after resize the text means size isn't change.

Comment: where do you resize the text? is it a native program, or do you do it in a browser???

Comment: Native program only. You can try http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1771/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html

Comment: man... this is not a native program, this is a web app what is running in a browser. anyway, in the top toolbar right side, you can change the font size. this is not a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Okay, this only works while change font size manually. but what i am asking is, if you drag the element it will change or not?

Comment: Stack overflow is for programmers, not for users. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic